# Static Pages >> sh.exe"; subl: command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, static-pages, sublimetext2

I'm going through an RoR guide, and i'm stuck at a problem in topic **"Static Pages"** and currently I'm using the text editor **Sublime Text 2** and whenever i follow instructions and do:

```
$subl .
```

or try

```
$subl public/hello.html
```

it outputs:

```
sh.exe" subl: command not found
```

any help would be very much appreciated..
-Marc

Comment: Have you added ~/bin/subl to your $PATH?

Comment: @SaidKaldybaev i believe not. what command do i do in order to add it to my ~/bin/subl ?

Answer (score 1):

if using ruby version manager (i am only assuming because i had this problem), then the suggested command for the symlink must be modified at the user path:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/.rvm/bin/subl
```

notice the .rvm directory has been added to the path.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue, the paths in $PATH were correct, and when I browsed to my local bin folder:

```
cd /usr/local/bin/
```

I could see the subl file / shortcut.

After pening this folder in finder with:

```
open .
```

I could see the icon looked incorrect (white), perhaps a previous version. Double clicking it also gave an error, so I manually copied the subl file over, after expanding contents of the Sublime Text 2.app.

If you drag the file over, it will create a shortcut, if that doesn't work then first duplicate the subl file in its original position, then drag over the duplicate and rename correctly. Or just give the correct permissions on it.

Hope this helps